# Multiple Labels for Counter() Data Frame Frame Objects in Matplotlib Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

I am doing a project on ICU dataset and I wanted to make double bar charts for survive and infection. I did it and it works fine as I[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p11Yp.png) have it here except now that I want to give a legend or label to it is not accepting and just wanted to know is there any ways that I can add a legend and rename my legends?
I want the red one shows the survive and the blue one show the infection

```
matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sys
import csv
import pandas as pd
import itertools
from collections import Counter
import pylab as pl
from matplotlib.dates import date2num
import datetime

with open('ICU.csv') as ICU:
#reads csv
df = pd.read_csv(ICU)
#arrays to hold csv data after parsed to int
Survive = []
Infection = []
# parse data column survive to int
for n in df.Survive:
  n =  int(n)
# adding the converted INT value to the Survive array
  Survive.append(n)
# parse data column Infection to int
for n in df.Infection:
 n =  int(n)

# adding the converted INT value to the Infection array
 Infection.append(n)
S = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Counter(Survive), orient='index')
I = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Counter(Infection), orient='index')
width = 0.4
fig = plt.figure() # Create matplotlib figure
ax = fig.add_subplot(111) # Create matplotlib axes
S.plot(kind='bar', color='red', ax=ax, width=width, position=1)
I.plot(kind='bar', color='blue', ax=ax, width=width, position=0, 
secondary_y=True)
plt.show()
```

seeds

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
plt.legend(labels=("survive", "infection"))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. i tried that already and is not working it just put the label on the top of each other without any other changes

Comment: Maybe I did not well understand your problem then. This is also caused by you not providing a [mcve]. But you should at least try to better describe what you want, what you get and in how far that does not meet your expectations.